# MultiValueDictKeyError at /register 'email'

Tags: django, authentication, view, model

i am trying to built a project where I have two users writer and reader and once I register them with checkbox writer and reader. Now when I try to login I get this error :

MultiValueDictKeyError at /register
'email'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:
'email'
register.html

Reader
    
    
        
        Writer

model.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   is_reader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_writer= models.BooleanField(default=False)

views.py 
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

    # Attempt to sign user in
    username = request.POST.get["username"]
    password = request.POST.get["password"]
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    # Check if authentication successful
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
       return render(request, "story/login.html", {
            "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
   else:
   return render(request, "story/login.html"
   def register(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST["username"]
    email = request.POST["email"]

   # Ensure password matches confirmation
   password = request.POST["password"]
    confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
   if password != confirmation:
       return render(request, "story/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
           user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
       except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "story/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
```

Comment: instead of email = request.POST["email"] you can use email = request.POST.get("email")

Comment: ok I tried, this is not working.